# Why don't my aliases in .bashrc work?

Tags: bash, alias

I have Lion on my Mac Air. I wrote some aliases in ~/.bashrc file, which looks like:

```
# Aliases
alias p='pdflatex *.tex;open *.pdf'
alias bromine='ssh administrator@bromine.org'
```

I then sourced my .bashrc file from .bash_profile, which I believe is sourced upon startup. My .bash_profile file looks like

```
# Setting PATH for EPD-7.2-2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

MKL_NUM_THREADS=1
export MKL_NUM_THREADS

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2012-02-27_at_18:19:09: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.

# source bashrc
. .bashrc
```

Why is it that my aliases work sometimes upon startup, but not always - (sometimes, I have to manually source .bash_profile)?

Comment: Can you identify a reproducible way to get a bash that doesn't have the aliases? When this happens, what does `ps -p $$ -p $PPID` show?

Comment: Have you tried sourcing with the full path, i.e. `${HOME}/.bashrc` instead of `.bashrc`?

Comment: I had similar issues a long time ago. I simply mashed everything into `.profile`, removed `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`, and stopped having issues.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a shot and see if loading the aliases becomes more reliable.

Comment: How do you startup?

Comment: The last line of your .bash_profile should be `source .bashrc` The way you are running it opens a session and then closes the session, any variables in that session will go away if you don't use the source command.

Answer (score 5):

It seems like your bash shell is looking for `.profile` instead of `.bashrc` . What you can do is make a symbolic link:

`ln -s ~/.bashrc ~/.profile`

and restart your session (close, reopen Terminal). Any future bash setting updates can be made to `.profile` or `.bashrc`.

Comment: That might be a fix but why has this happened that seems a nasty bug. What else is broken